# C++ Class is not base of itself

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

Im not exactly sure how much information is needed to answer this, so tell me if more information is needed.

Im modifying a large code i wrote when i suddenly encountered this message: `error: type 'integer' is not a direct base of 'integer'`. i know its an inheritance problem, but im not inheriting other classes.

The code that is causing this problem is

```
integer(const std::string & val, uint16_t base): integer(val.begin(), val.end(), base) {}
```

and

```
integer(iterator start, iterator end, uint16_t base)
```

has been defined.

What do I need to do to fix this?

EDIT: im compiling with -std=c++0x, which according to the answers, i should be able to compile, unless my compiler is old: gcc 4.6.2 i think

Comment: Update answer, available in gcc 4.7 onwards.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to call another constructor directly. You can't do that in C++03, but you [can do exactly that in C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Object_construction_improvement):

> ```
> class SomeType  {
>     int number;
>
> public:
>     SomeType(int new_number) : number(new_number) {}
>     SomeType() : SomeType(42) {}
> };
> ```

You'll need g++ 4.7 or newer for this to work, 4.6 doesn't support this feature yet, even with -std=c++0x, which I tested with both versions on my system.

Comment: @calccrypto GCC 4.6 doesn't support this. 4.7 does I think.

Answer (score 4):

It is not allowed to invoke other constructors of the same `class` like that (there are delegating constructors in C++11). You need to initialise the members of the class (as you have probably done in the other constructor).

EDIT:

According to [C++0x/C++11 Support in GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html)
, delegating constructors were implemented in GCC v4.7

Answer (score 3):

You can't call a constructor of the same class in the initializer list of a different constructor (in C++03). But you can initialize the members accordingly:

```
integer(const std::string & val, uint16_t base): _start(val.begin())
                                                 _end(val.end())
                                                 _base(base)
{}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's [not supported in g++-4.6](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/cxx0x_status.html) ("Delegating constructors  |  N1986  |    No"), but [is supported in 4.7](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/cxx0x_status.html).