# unique_ptr to object array , constructor has different behavior

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

I have the following c++ test compiled at g++ 4.4.6 with --std=c++0x :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std ;

class Arrs
{
private :
    int i ;
public:
    Arrs(int i_=0):i(i_){ cout << "cons" << endl ; }
    void setinArr(int i_){i = i_ ; }
    ~Arrs(){ cout << "(" << i << ")" << endl ; }
};

class MM
{
private:
    int icnt ;
    unique_ptr<Arrs[]> ptr ;
public:
    MM(int i_):icnt(i_){ ptr.reset( new Arrs[i_] ); }
    void setinMM(int i_,int j_){
        //ptr[i_] = j_ ;
        ptr[i_].setinArr(j_)  ;
    }
    ~MM(){}
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    MM m(5) ;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        m.setinMM(i,50+i) ;
}
```

my question is :  if I  code : ptr[i_].setinArr(j_)  in setinMM the output would be :

```
cons
cons
cons
cons
cons
(54)
(53)
(52)
(51)
(50)
```

if  I code ptr[i_] = j_  instead ,  the output would be :

```
cons
cons
cons
cons
cons
cons
(50)
cons
(51)
cons
(52)
cons
(53)
cons
(54)
(54)
(53)
(52)
(51)
(50)
```

I have no idea what happen ptr[i_] = j_ ;  in MM.setinMM cause this output ,
any hint ?!

Comment: This has nothing to do with unique_ptrs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't overload `operator=` for an `int` assignment, then the following statement:

```
ptr[i_] = j_ ;
```

uses an implicitly defined *copy-assignment-operator*:

```
Arrs& Arrs::operator=(const Arrs&)
```

by creating a temporary instance of `Arrs` through a *copy-initialization* with `j_` as an argument, and passing that temporary into the operator. Creating the temporary is where the additional prints come from.

Such mistakes could be avoided by declaring constructors callable with a single argument as `explicit`, by replacing:

```
Arrs(int i_ = 0) : i(i_) {}
```

with the two declared as follows:

```
Arrs() : Arrs(0) {}  // make sure default constructor is not explicit
explicit Arrs(int i_) : i(i_) {} // make explicit this one
```

or (if *delegating constructors* are not supported) with:

```
Arrs() : i(0) {}
explicit Arrs(int i_) : i(i_) {}
```

Comment: , thanks , my env is c++0x , not in c++11 , according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391108/c-class-is-not-base-of-itself  , call another constructor directly is not supported in C++0x , your code help a lot , my confusing gone !!